# How to generate random numbers with r.nextInt() except one number?

Tags: java, random

I've come to a part in my code where I must generate a random number every time I press a button (r in this case). When I press this button, I want it to generate a number between 0 and n (3 in this case), but I don't want it to generate a number it previously generated. So I do not want the same number to be generated twice in a row. So 2 then 2 is bad. 2 then 0 then 2 is OK however.

I've looked around on here for questions similar to mine but none of them have really helped. Everyone else is generating once with the exception of numbers in an array or something. I'm constantly generating and I want to be able to detect the same number previous.

I am using the Random class, I have considered using the math.random class but that is between 0 and 1 so that isn't really too useful. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks! :D

Comment: How about you generate a random number and check if it's the same that was just generated. If it is, generate a new random number. Repeat until you get something new. This is basic programming, nothing complicated.

Comment: You can multiply the result of math.random() (a value between zero and one) by any number you want to control the range of your random numbers.

Comment: Sorry if I have confused anyone. When I generate a number, I do not want it to be the same as the previous one that was generated. Every other number is OK. Also, I've tried checking if it is the same number until I get something new but I'm having trouble doing that within the code I have. Thanks for your help guys btw :)

Answer (score 6):

Memorize what you generated last time; repeat generating until they are different

Say you want numbers 0-9

```
do
{
    int n = Random.nextInt(10);

} while (n == prev) // prev is the number you generated previously
prev = n;
```

Comment: Based on how the question is written, this is the solution. No need to make it complicated!

Answer (score 4):

Since you have n possible values for the first, and only n-1 for the subsequent, just use `randInt` with a different argument depending on whether you're producing the first value or not.  Trying to use `randInt` with the same arguments for all iterations will result in a non-flat distribution.

```
class NoAdjacentPRNG implements Iterator<Integer> {
  private final Random rnd;
  private final int range;  // 3 to generate numbers in [0, 2).
  private Integer last;

  NoAdjacentPRNG(Random rnd, int range) {
    this.rnd = rnd;
    this.range = range;
  }

  public boolean hasNext() { return true; }
  public Integer next() {
    int n;
    if (last == null) {
      // The first time through, there are range possible values.
      n = rnd.nextInt(range);
    } else {
      // There are only range-1 possible values given that the
      // last is excluded.
      n = rnd.nextInt(range - 1);
      // Work around last.
      if (n >= last) { ++n; }
    }
    last = n;
    return n;
  }

  public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
}
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey, rewrote to make adjacency the only restriction.

Comment: you didn't initialize your variables!

Comment: Well nevermind. I don't remember seeing the constructor when I looked before, maybe I'm just going crazy.

Comment: @Jyro117, Maybe both of us are crazy.  I added a ctor in an edit, but I thought I did that before you asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
int[] values = new int[360];
values[0] = random.nextInt(n+1);
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    values[i] = random.nextInt(n);
    if (values[i-1] == values[i]) values[i] = n;
}
```

Comment: Sorry this isn't too helpful - I didn't specify but I will need to generate 360 numbers and make sure it doesn't generate the same number twice. But thanks for answering!

Comment: @HaydenPerry Oh, in that case you would have to use a loop.  I would hope you know how to use one of those? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can even be super-simple:

```
public class NonRepeatingRandom extends Random {
  private int last = -1;
  @Override
  public int nextInt(int i) {
    int next = super.nextInt(i);
    while ( next == last) {
      next = super.nextInt(i);
    }
    return last = next;
  }
}
```